# Show additional data when checkbox is true Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I'm working at my first project in Django and learning it by the way. Currently I'm stuck at the part of the project where I have to show additional data if checkbox is selected as true.

Long story short, there have to be checkbox at my page which name is "Cars", if user check the checkbox as True, select list of models of cars should be displayed immediately, below this checkbox, without affecting other input sources on current page.

Is there easy way how to accomplis this? Thanks for help.

/edit

HTML code

```
        <p class="dhcp"> DHCP: {{ form.dhcp }} </p>
        <p class="collapse1 collapse"> IPv4 adresy: {{form.ipv4_adress }} </p>

        <p class="dhcpv6"> DHCPv6: {{ form.dhcpv6 }} </p>
        <p class="collapse2 collapse"> IPv6 adresy: {{form.ipv6_adress }} </p>
```

JS code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $(".dhcp").click(function(event) {
         $(".collapse1").fadeToggle().delay(100);
     });

     $(".dhcpv6").click(function(event) {
         $(".collapse2").fadeToggle().delay(100);
     });
 })
```

It's just part of it, its quite "big" by now and not telling anything because of being generated by django form. Main issue right now is that if I click on same row as is checkbox, it trigger action of displaying data.

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic you will need to use javascript.

Comment: Is that Django-specific, or just a simple javascript, front-end issue?

Comment: To be honest i've got no frontend/backend experiences yet, this is my summer intern position and my boss just got a free week so I can't also ask anybody competent. Does that mean it's impossible to accomplish it by django forms? What I'm working at should be working form at the end, so I guess it's not banned for me to use javascript, but also he didn't mentioned it.

Comment: You need to explain in more detail. If you just want it to show on page load then you would only need to do `{% if whatever %}`.

Comment: I was currently reading about it but user would have to submit his choice first. I am going to edit question to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: so is my solution working or not? @FilipM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this  [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zg96e5a/12/)  . Its a simple JS solution with a fadeToggle for your problem. The Delay of 100 is optional but it makes the hole thing more elegant although this stays in conflict with your "should be displayed immediately" ;)

```
<input class="collapsed" type="checkbox">Cars
<div class="collapse2 collapse" style="display:none;">
   <li>car hello</li>
   <li>car lala</li>
   <li>car 1</li>
</div>

$(".collapsed").click(function(event){
    $(".collapse2").fadeToggle().delay(100);
})
```

If there are multiple checkboxes like this you maybe would have to use the `this` keyword in JS.

That should do the Trick if not leave a comment.

Comment: @FilipM happy to help please remember to interact when somebody took the time to answer your question. You don't have to up vote or select an answer but a simple "thanks" is appreciated :)

Comment: understand that fully but I didn't actually tried it before, so didn't want to post just empty thanks, anyway once again thanks for help :-)

Comment: I found out that it actually doesn't work as it should completely, even clicking in same line as is checkbox located triggers action, is there any way how to solve this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4zg96e5a/14/ check this JSfiddle. Here you need to click in the checkbox. JSFiddle I posted in my answer is different I added a label. With a label you can click in the same line and it gets checked. You can post your code in a JSFiddle and send me the link I will see what I can do @FilipM

Comment: whats the difference beetween the two? can't see only character different, my html is mostly generated by django form so it's not possible for me to post it into jsfiddle. How could I solve this issue? and what do you mean by label?

Comment: look at the fiddle I posted in the comment. In the HTML there is a `label`. Do you have that in your code in your project? Because this makes the whole part of the form clickable to check a checkbox. Its kinda hard to explain. In the second JSFiddle you can click on the text and the box will be checked in the first one you have to click in the box to check it. Please post the code you have (edit your question on top) and explain detailed what the problem is. I need to know how it is now and how it should be (post an image if you have trouble explaining)

Comment: done, but there is no label in my html code, it either means there is other issue or its somehow generated by django. Sometimes its not so good to have such powerful framework, especially when I don't know what am I doing with it as beginner.